# How to add json values to db columns?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to add json data into my column
Assume
Table A have one column called expected_date
I need to add this json value to this column
{"lock":"false","date":"10/14/2021"}

Please help me out

Comment: what's your DBMS(and preferably the version)? `MySQL` and `Oracle` are different products of DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

- JSON can be added using proper structure in **single quotes**.
- Demo -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNcR9EtAEKGEsbDEMrDtdV/2

```
create table a (
    some_column varchar(50)
);

insert into a values ('{"a":"b"}');

update a 
set some_column = '{"c":"d"}'
where some_column = '{"a":"b"}';
```

Comment: Same thing using update please and my table have varchar data type for that column